# Is state guaranteed to be reinstated when UIApplicationWillEnterForeground gets called

Tags: swift, swift4

Is the state of my app guaranteed to be reinstated when `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` notification gets called?

In other words, if I have a private boolean field set to true, will that variable still be true if I check its value in my `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` notification method handler when transitioning from the background to the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,  When the App enters the background, it still stays in memory, however if memory runs low, the iOS begins to release these suspended apps to make room for those that must be loaded. So basically if you want to ensure that there is no data loss, you must save app data and settings in:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

}
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Ill ensure to persist my state in my backing store. I'll accept your answer in 4 minutes. And congrats on breaking 1000

Comment: You're supposed to save state in your `applicationWillResignActive` call, not in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. And note that in modern iOS versions, `applicationWillTerminate` is rarely called. Usually the user swaps the app by pressing the home button, you get told you're leaving the active state, and then get terminated without further warning.

Comment: Duncan as per the comments in AppDelegate itself.... Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.

Comment: @DuncanC Why persist state inwillResignActive and not didEnterBackground? Is it due to interruptions, like a phone call?

Comment: This answer isn't really correct. The question asks if app state is guaranteed to be restored when `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` is posted. The answer is effectively yes because if that notification is sent, it means the app entered the background and then returned to the foreground. This means the app was not killed or restarted. The app state is not actually restored because it doesn't need to be restored in this case.

Comment: @rmaddy So what you're saying is 'UIApplicationWillEnterForeground' would not be invoked in the event the OS terminates the application? If an app is terminated by the OS would the user have to relaunch the app? They wouldn't be able to double press the home button and navigate to the application via the app switcher?

Comment: @WBuck If an app is terminated (for any reason) then when the user launches it again, the app will be fully restarted. When fully restarted, `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` is not sent. You can test all of this with a simple test app. Implement all of the app delegate methods and set breakpoints.

Comment: @rmaddy I have done this, and in 99.9% of the cases the boolean variable I was talking about in my OP was set to a value that I expected. But, I did see something really weird in one of the tests I had run which I was never able to reproduce. `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` was called twice. On the first call the boolean variable was set to false, and on the second call the variable was set to true.. Thats partially what prompted me to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you get told that your app is being suspended, (Via a call to `applicationWillResignActive`) you should save your app state. Your app may then be activated again while still in memory, or it may be terminated. If you get reactivated again, all of your app's variables will still have their previous values. If not, you will be launched "cold" and you will need to restore your saved state.

At the time you are told that you are going to switch to the inactive state you can't know if you will get reactivated or terminated. Thus the answer to your question is **no**. You might get killed, not reactivated.

### EDIT:

Apple's docs say:

> **Handle Deactivation**
>
> When a foreground app moves to the background, UIKit first calls
> the applicationWillResignActive: method to deactivate the app. When
> deactivation occurs, do the following.
>
> - Save user data to disk and close any open files. Always save user
>   data in case your app needs to be terminated. Close files in case the
>   user locks the device.
> - Do only work that’s critical to preserving the user’s data. Pause
>   dispatch queues and operation queues, and don’t schedule any new tasks
>   for execution.
> - Invalidate any active timers.

Comment: App state should be saved when you enter the background, not when resigning active. An inactive app won't be killed. A backgrounded app can be killed.

Comment: That's not what the Apple docs say. See my edits. I think part of the confusion is Apple's varied use of the term "background." They sometimes uses it to mean an app that is getting background CPU time, and other times to refer to an app that is not the foreground app.

Comment: What we're really talking about is an app in the suspended state (in memory but no longer getting CPU time) but there is no specific notification that you are entering the suspended state. I think Apple tells you to save state in response to applicationWillResignActive because normally you don't get much time in the background state before being suspended.